# OpenSSL HMAC-SHA1 digest does not match Crypto's

Tags: php, node.js, digest, hmacsha1

I've spent past 6 hours implementing message signing algorithm.. It does not work AT ALL:

This is PHP code to generate digest:

```
$payload = "thisisanapple";
$signature = hash_hmac("sha1", $payload, "thisisarandomkey");
$data = base64_encode($signature);
// YzExZWRmZDliMjQzNTZjNzhlNmE3ZTdmMDE3ODJjNmMxMmM4ZTllMQ==
```

This is JS running on the Node.js server doing the same thing:

```
var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha1', "thisisarandomkey");
hmac.update("thisisanapple");
var signature = hmac.digest('base64');
// wR7f2bJDVseOan5/AXgsbBLI6eE=
```

I have no clue what is wrong here.. I have tries SHA256, but they still differ. I also used a private key generated with OpenSSL, both in plaintext and in base64, still same result (different keys).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hash_hmac` has four parameters and the last one specifies the output and by default `hash_hmac` returns hex string, not the raw data. So `base64_encode` encodes hex string in the PHP code fragment.

This one will work well:

```
$payload = "thisisanapple";
$signature = hash_hmac("sha1", $payload, "thisisarandomkey", true);
$data = base64_encode($signature);
// wR7f2bJDVseOan5/AXgsbBLI6eE=
```

Comment: Do you know what would be the JS code to match the PHP behaviour in the original question?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to duplicate the PHP behaviour in JS, here is the code:

```
hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha1', 'thisisarandomkey')
signature = hmac.update('thisisanapple')
data = new Buffer(hmac.digest('hex')).toString('base64')
```